# java.lang.RuntimeException: InputChannel is not initialized

Tags: android

I am developing an android application. I meet with this crash many times
recently and I have found this issue https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=108859,is there any way to avoid this crash ?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: InputChannel is not initialized.
    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeInit(InputEventReceiver.java)
    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.<init>(InputEventReceiver.java)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java)
    at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```